# ball goes off the screen

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, 2d

i have been trying to make a bouncing ball animation.I have got everything right except for one thing.
The ball goes off the screen once it hits the lower deck of the frame and the right hand side of it's frame.

**I have set the condition like :**

```
if( x_Pos > frameWidth - ballRadius)
  // turn the ball back
if( y_Pos > frameHeight - ballRadius)
  // turn the ball back
```

But the ball disappears for a while when it hits the lower deck and the right deck of the frame.
Here is what happens eventually :
[image]

[image]

**In the second pic ball has hit the lower deck and has disappeared for a while.** *Why this happens ?*

In case this is my complete code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class MovingBall2D extends JPanel{

 int x_Pos=0;
 int y_Pos=30;
 int speedX=1;
 int speedY=1;
 int diameter=30;
 int height=30;
 int frameX=700;
 int frameY=200;
 int radius=diameter/2;

 MovingBall2D() {
  this.setSize(frameX,frameY);
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     if(x_Pos < 0) {
      x_Pos = 0;
      speedX = 1;
     }
     else if( x_Pos >= ( frameX - radius ) ) {
      x_Pos =  frameX - diameter;
      speedX = -1; 
     }
     if(y_Pos < 0) {
      y_Pos = 0;
      speedY = 1;
     }
     else if( y_Pos >= ( frameY - radius ) ) {
      y_Pos =  frameY - radius; 
      speedY = -1;
     } 
     x_Pos = x_Pos + speedX;
     y_Pos = y_Pos + speedY;    
     repaint();
    }
   };
    new Timer(4,taskPerformer).start();
  }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0,0,frameX,frameY);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillOval(x_Pos , y_Pos , diameter , height);
   }
  }

   class Main2D {
    Main2D() {
     JFrame fr=new JFrame();
     MovingBall2D o = new MovingBall2D();
     fr.add(o);
     fr.setSize(600,200);
     fr.setVisible(true);
     fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } 

     public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Main2D();
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MovingBall2D.this.getHeight() is 173(because of panel padding,title,border etc.). That's why

Just replace the if conidion like so:

```
    else if( y_Pos >= ( MovingBall2D.this.getHeight()- radius ) )
    {
        y_Pos = MovingBall2D.this.getHeight() - radius;
        speedY = -1;
    }
```

The advantage of this is that even if the user resizes the window, the ball will hit the new window boundaries. Do the same for X axis.

Comment: that is because you have to change the line inside if block to: y_Pos = MovingBall2D.this.getHeight() - radius; I though its obvious :0 Anyway i have updated my answer. can u please remove the down vote now

Comment: @ Suraj Chandran yes it works ! Can you please explain `MovingBall2D.this.getHeight()`. **I mean the call,,how are you calling getHeight() and getwidth()**

Comment: sure. The else block is inside an anonymous actionlistener. So "this" will resolve to the actionlistener instance. What we need is to get the current instance of MovingBall2D object. When you are inside an anonymous class, to access the instance of parent class, you do PARENTCLASS.this, which is exactly what i have done there. I see that you are in college, doing you SCJP will cover such things :)

Comment: what if the else block wasn't there in the anonymous class.Then how the call to `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` be.

Comment: its not because of the if-else block, its because of the reason that we are inside a anonymous class

Comment: @ Suraj Chandran that is what i asked.What if we were outside the anonymous class ?

Comment: then you could directly do this.getHeight()

Comment: @ Suraj Chandran can you tell me the difference between `super` and `this` ?

Comment: this is used to refer to the members of current class, whereas super is used to refer to the member of parent class

Answer (score 4):

Basically it is because you set your `JFrame` to be 200 px tall which then means that your panel will have less height (minus title and borders).

Additionally your ball extends from `(xpos, ypos)` to `(xpos+diameter,ypos+diameter)` and thus the correct condition would be `y_Pos > frameHeight - ballDiameter` instead of `y_Pos > frameHeight - ballRadius`.

Comment: can you please elaborate the line `Basically it is because you set your JFrame to be 200 px tall which then means that your panel will have less height (minus title and borders).`

Comment: You set the JFrame's size to absolute 200px (measured complete height, incl. Title). This means that your component inside is less than 200px tall (because of the borders which also take some space). In your code you assume that the component is always 200px tall which isn't e case.

Comment: @ Howard this thing `y_Pos > frameHeight - ballDiameter` does not work.Ball still goes slightly below the frame. **How can i know the actual width and height of my drawing area/panel?**

Comment: @ Howard can you please explain the call `MovingBall2D.this.getHeight()`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the frame width you use (700) is larger than the actual size of the component (600). Use JPanel.getWidth() and JPanel.getHeight() to get actual coordinates instead of hard-coded.

Comment: when i use JPanel.getWidth() and JPanel.getHeight() i get an error that **Main2D.java:25: non-static method getWidth() cannot be referenced from a static context
       else if( x_Pos >= ( MovingBall2D.getWidth() - radius ) ) {
                                       ^
Main2D.java:33: non-static method getHeight() cannot be referenced from a static context
       else if( y_Pos >= ( MovingBall2D.getHeight() - radius ) )  {
                                       ^
2 errors**

Comment: @Suhall Gupta: I meant use these methods of the panel. in your case, just getHeight() and getWidth() should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try not resetting the position, instead using Tuple2D to clamp the position of the ball. I haven't coded enough in java to really know the correct syntax and whatnot, but google should help.